# Bootstrap datetime picker picking day before selected

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I am using [this](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) bootstrap datetime picker. I noticed that when I choose a day and convert the milliseconds using `var d1 = new Date(milliseconds);` it is converted into the day before my selected day. Is there a particular reason for this?

**Example:**

I select Tuesday, October 1st:

[image]

I log the date object after it is converted:

[image]

Comment: Just to rule it out, your local system is set to use the EDT timezone, yes? And can you provide a jsfiddle or jsbin that replicates the problem?

Comment: Yes my system is in EDT, I will have to put together a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must convert it into a [**Unix timestamp**](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) , which is a better way of tracking date/time.

Use `new Date('your_date_string').getTime() / 1000` which gives you the timestamp or using PHP ([**strtotime**](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php))  .
The date object that is being logged for you is probably coming from your system/browser settings(local).

Do not use JavaScript date and time calculations in web applications unless you ABSOLUTELY have to.

While you have the timestamp, [cross-check](http://www.epochconverter.com/) if you are getting the correct time.

Comment: The datetime picker gives me milliseconds. `new Date('your_date_string').getTime() / 1000` logs this form: `1380913626.728 `

Comment: Using the converter I get the correct time. Now I just have to display it. Why exactly does it give me the day before (still curious)?

Comment: When given a date string in ISO format, JavaScript assumes it's in UTC.Javascript will use the end user's local computer clock where PHP will use the time and timezone settings of the remote server. Try creating a sample page that outputs the current time and timezone offset in PHP and compare that with the computer you are on.

Comment: how do you convert the unix timestamp into something readable?

Comment: I am using javascript to convert it - right now when i try to convert it to something readable, the date returns to being inaccurate.

Comment: `$('your_date_picker_element').val()` should give u the date string ?
In php use `date("m/d/Y h:i:s",$unixtime);`

Comment: after i convert the milliseconds to a unix timestamp, if i convert it back with *1000, the date is inaccurate again

Comment: Check my updated answer, ive attached an image ... `.val()` is giving me the date string of datepicker...im on the datepicker plugin page

Comment: Yeah I see that, but mine prints a blank line to the console. I must be doing something wrong I will keep looking.

Comment: I am guessing the id/class of the element attached with datepicker is incorrect or is it?

Comment: I have two datepickers: `<div id="beginDate"` and `<div id="beginDate"` When I write `$('#beginDate').val()` and log it it logs an empty string.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, i included the `#`

Comment: Why don't you give different ids to each and do `.val()`

Comment: I still log a blank line.

Comment: oh i get it, why are u using a `<div>`  use a nice `<input>` mate

Comment: wow i can't believe that was the mistake. thank you for spending time with me to help. I have the `input` inside the `div` but have been trying to use the `div`'s id instead of the `input`'s